# Two dimensional array scan algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, math

I have being given with a question to scan 2 dimensional array, the array represent a garden, u can step on the garden grass only if the grass is cut down and not too high. a cut down grass represented by number 1. high grass represented with a number bigger then 1, the bigger the number - the higher the grass, **heights are unique**. in this garden you can have *ant colonies* which is represented by 0. you can't step on ant colony, no matter what.

Your goal is to cut down all the grass and make it level 1, but u must cat the smallest grass first before you cut any bigger grass. u start from any corner of the garden u choose, as long as u don't stand on an ant colony.
once u cut a grass, it will become number 1, which means, u can now step on it, remember, u can't step on grass bigger then number 1.

Edit:
- heights are unique
The algorithm should return the number of steps made (else -1) , obviously the less steps the better, and you can't go out of the board.

**Example:**
this matrix

```
 [1,1,1,0] 
 [1,0,2,1]
 [1,0,3,1]
```

**output:** 3, because u start from the bottom right cornet, then, u go up, and then left, (chop the grass) and then down (chop grass again).

suggested solution:

is using some kind of a flood fill algorithm (recursion in all directions), and in any case use calculated data structure - like min heap, to hold the current smallest grass height so far, without a pre-clculated min heap we can't never know if we can cut the grass. we take the minimum number from the heap, and start searching for it in the matrix. every cell we encounter, we will go in all directions to search for the number we want.

This solution is obviously the worst, but it solve the problem. I was just wandering if someone can have a better one, I can imagine some dynamic programming solution maybe, not sure. Hell =D

Comment: And what is the question here? "Please solve this for me" is not a valid question for Stack Overflow. If you have tried and failed, that might be a valid question.

Comment: You did not show us any attempt or effort to solve it. This is not a valid question.

Comment: So what I understand from your question is that, I can travel on the grass where the height is 1 and as soon as I encounter grass height to be greater than 1 in all the other directions of the cell where I am standing right now, I can cut the grass and bring them to level one and now I have new cells to move onto, something like this right ? Can you also post an input 2D matrix that will have cell values of 0,1 and > 1, I will try to come up with a solution and code

Comment: NOTE: I edited my question, the heights are unique, and if u can't have answer u can return -1. an example matrix is also shown above

Comment: zenwraight  - no, it's true that I can travel on number 1, but I can only cut the grass of the lowest height at any given time, that's why in my example, I have 3 steps instead of 2, because I must first cut the cell with height 2 (which is currently the lowest height) and then then the height 3

Comment: u can also have multiple path to a cell as shown in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm that finds the shortest path (with the minimum number of steps):

1. Collect all cells with `height > 1` and sort them by height in increasing order. (They are all unique).
2. Add the starting cell to the beginning of the sorted collection of cells.
3. Iterate through the collection and find the shortest path between the current cell and the next cell in the collection, assuming that all cells with higher heights are the ant colonies (cannot be visited). This can be done with [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Example:

   ```
   1 2 4 
   1 3 0 
   1 1 1
   ```

   On the first iteration, we need to find the shortest path between bottom-right corner and cell with `height = 2`. We should run BFS in the 'virtual garden' where all cells with `height > 2` are impossible to go through:

   ```
   1 2 0 
   1 0 0 
   1 1 1
   ```

   Note, that you need not change higher cells to zero value, just to change the condition in BFS.
4. Join all found shortest paths.